# Why the results from 2D diffusion simulation are different with different dx?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm making numerical 2D diffusion simulation code with python, and I have a big problem.

Simulation results change when I increase spatial interval value (dx).

Why is this happening? I think that it is not about stabilization problem.

Have you experienced about that? Please let me know what the problem is.

I put an example code I made.

- 2D diffusion equation.

  dC/dt = D*(d^2C/dx^2 + d^2C/dy^2)
- Discretize the above equation.
  (n : time, i : x axis, j : y axis, dx=dy)

  C[n+1,i,j] = C[n,i,j] + D*(dt/dx^2)*(C[n,i+1,j]+C[n,i-1,j]+C[n,i,j+1]+C[n,i,j-1]-4C[n,i,j])

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T0 = 1e-6 ## 1 us
L0 = 1e-7 ## 100 nm

## Matrix shift
def matrix_shift(CC,ixmax,iymax):
    CC_pn = np.zeros([ixmax,iymax]);CC_mn = np.zeros([ixmax,iymax])
    CC_np = np.zeros([ixmax,iymax]);CC_nm = np.zeros([ixmax,iymax])
    CC_pn[0:ixmax-1,:] = CC[1:,:]; CC_pn[ixmax-1,:] = CC[ixmax-1,:]
    CC_mn[1:,:] = CC[0:ixmax-1,:]; CC_mn[0,:] = CC[0,:]
    CC_np[:,0:iymax-1] = CC[:,1:]; CC_np[:,iymax-1] = CC[:,iymax-1]
    CC_nm[:,1:] = CC[:,0:iymax-1]; CC_nm[:,0] = CC[:,0]
    CC_sum = CC_pn+CC_mn+CC_np+CC_nm
    return CC_sum

dx = 2e-8/L0 ## 20 nm
itmax = int(1e3); ixmax = int(25*(0.2/dx)+1);iymax = int(39*(0.2/dx)+1)      
d7 = 2.2e-10*(T0/(L0**2));dt = (dx**2)/(6.*d7);uu = (dt)/(dx**2)

time_array= np.linspace(0,itmax-1,int(itmax))*dt*1.e3*T0
xarray = np.linspace(0,ixmax-1,ixmax)*dx*1e9*L0

## Initial conditions
CC7 = np.zeros([ixmax,iymax])
ii = int(2./dx); jj = int(4./dx); CC7[ii,jj]=1.
result_ca = np.zeros(itmax)

for it in range(int(itmax)):
    CC7 = CC7 + d7*uu*(matrix_shift(CC7,ixmax,iymax)-4.*CC7)
    result_ca[it] = CC7[ii,jj]

plt.plot(time_array,result_ca); plt.show()
```

I expect the results are same with different dx.

Comment: How do the simulation results change if you change dx? Could you maybe simplify the code (and the used equations) even further and still see a problem? What about sufficiently small dx? Is the result still depending on them then?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a mathematical / numerical issue than a problem of code. It is not surprising that changing the space grid changes the results. Indeed, here you are descretizing a continuous mathematical equation, this creates an error that gets bigger with a coarser grid. So the smaller dx is, the more accurate your result is going to be (same goes for time discretization).

Regarding numerical instability check for example the [Courant–Friedrichs–Lewy condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courant%E2%80%93Friedrichs%E2%80%93Lewy_condition) to get more information about why and when it occurs for explicit schemes.